# Visual Studio RDL Report New Page per record

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rdl

I have this RDL report that I created in Visual Studio and it is using a Stored Procedure as the data source. Every column from the SP output is mapped to a text box in the report.

Now, the SP returns multiple rows but in the report, only one of them is getting printed.

I want the report to create a new page for each row returned from the SP.

Is it possible? If so, then how I can do that? All inputs are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a group which ends up being one record per group (RowNumber, etc...) and use the [Page Break settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251733%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on the group header and hide the detail rows so that only the group or footer is visible.